# Programmatically changing textview in Linear Layout depending on user attributes

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to programmatically change a textview depending whether or not an ArrayList is available. Basically, I had three different RecyclerView Adapters  & TextViews to display a user's pets, kids and cars. If a person does not have one of these, I blank the RecyclerView and want to delete that textview and move everything up to replace it.  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6JuY.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v1OM.png

[image: TextView]

The only thing that has worked for me is to use TextView.setVisibility(View.GONE). But obviously, that doesn't work for me. 
I've tried this as suggested in a different question:

```
LinearLayout lL = new LinearLayout(getContext());
lL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
Pets.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

However, that doesn't work for me either in terms of pushing it up.

Comment: make your RecyclerView setVisibility(View.GONE)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the visibility of your `RecyclerView` as `View.GONE`.

Comment: that's not answer that is a comment

Comment: @GokhanArik I would have commented if I had enough reputation points. I only wanted to help.

Comment: edit your answer and recommend to hide RecyclerView and people will upvote back

Comment: There is still a blank space in the layout. It looks like #2 in my diagram.

Comment: collapsing layout,tablayout will simply helps you(my answer). try that I will help you in further implementation for that